# resize/grow jface treeviewer dynamically

Tags: java, tree, treeview, swt, jface

Is it possible to resize/growthe Jface treeviewer  dynamically ?

I mean we have a composite and treeviewer has some contents, and user is clicking on the expand button to expand the contents, now parallely can the treeviewer grow ??

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? It is hard to see what you are asking for.

Comment: problem is that, I have treeviewer with size

GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
treeViewer.getTree().setLayoutData(gridData);
gridData.heightHint = 150;

This creates a lot of empty white space, because when the dialog opens the tree is by default collapsed to root, so a lot of white space shows up. If I don't set the initial heightHint for the gridata, then its opens up very small.

I want to avoid the excessive white space displayed to user.

Comment: Please post code in your question. Use the `edit` link below the question. Why are you setting a "fixed" height in the first place? Shouldn't the `Layout` take care of everything?

Answer (score 0):

You should not "grow" the `TreeViewer` this way. Imagine the scenario where the `TreeViewer` is to large to fit on the screen.

The way to go is using a [`ScrolledComposite`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FScrolledComposite.html) that hosts the `TreeViewer`. This scrolled composite can be set to a default size and will show scrollbars when the content is to large for that size.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesScrolledComposite.htm) is a simple example on how to use `ScrolledComposite`. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Even if I use the scrolled composite, the default state of my tree is collapsed, and there is a lot of white space showing

Comment: Then show the tree "uncollapsed"? I'm just saying that you should rethink your requirements.

Comment: tree is huge and its a heavy loading time to user